# "ImportError: Cannot import name mongoclient" in Windows

Tags: python, windows, mongodb, pymongo

I'm calling the following simple script to connect to a mongo database via Python.

I am facing the error while running this below program in windows

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
```

Here is the below error

```
C:\Python27>python pymongo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymongo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "C:\Python27\pymongo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pymongo import MongoClient
ImportError: cannot import name MongoClient
```

Can somebody please help me on this

Answer (score 31):

You named your script `pymongo.py`, which masks the `pymongo` module from which you are importing.

Rename your script to something else (and delete the `pymongo.pyc` file if one was created next to it).